# C++: browse filenames in Windows which have dots inside the names

Tags: c++, windows, file, winapi, directory

Let's take as example the following file name: `abc.def.txt`. I'm using `FindFirstFileA()` and `FindNextFileA()` in order to browse a directory. The function looks like this:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string>* readDir(std::string pattern) {
    auto v = new std::vector<std::string>;
    pattern.append("\\*");
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA data;
    HANDLE hFind;
    if ((hFind = FindFirstFileA(pattern.c_str(), &data)) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            v->push_back(data.cFileName);
        } while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &data) != 0);
        FindClose(hFind);
    }
    return v;
}
```

The problem is that the filename mentioned earlier will appear as `abcdef.txt` or `abc def.txt`. What can I do to get the names of files with their dots?

Comment: `throw new NotFoundException`. That's not how you do it in C++, we just use `throw NotFoundException`. The return type also is a pointer for no good reason.

Comment: And really, we don't use exceptions for control flow either. If you don't find any files, just return an empty vector. Not even going into how you're leaking memory left and right. Or how you're planning to fit a Unicode file name inside an ANSI-encoded string.

Comment: I edited the question so people can focus on the main problem

Comment: If you want people to focus on the problem, take out all the C++ code. If you *insist* on using C++, at least drop the parts no-one is using anymore (raw pointers and `operator new`).

Comment: Don't know how you test, but I can't reproduce with this code. PS: use unicode version. Forget about ansi API on Windows (but this is not the issue here)

Comment: `FindFirstFileA` does not modify the filename other than to encode it using the active codepage of the process, which is potentially a lossy encoding if the active codepage isn't UTF-8 (a per-application setting in Windows 10). If you can't set the application active codepage to UTF-8 for some reason, or still have to support Windows 8 (or even Windows 7), then IMO the entire multibyte-character (ANSI) API is garbage that should not be used. Users should not be restricted to using names that can be encoded with legacy codepages from the 1980s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're finding the old 8.3 name. You'd want `FindFirstFileEx` with level `FindExInfoBasic`. This ignores 8.3 names.

Comment: No, the code shows `cFileName` referenced. That is never the short 8.3 name unless the two happen to be the same. The 8.3 name is returned in the `cAlternateFileName` field.

Comment: Also, a short name never contains spaces as in "abc def.txt". It's not allowed even if manually set via `SetFileShortName`, which will fail it as an invalid parameter.